# PHP regex for Lebanese phone number

Tags: php, regex

i am writing a php app that asks people for their phone number in lebanon. I don't want to be very strict in the entry format so i'm running into some trouble validating.

A lebanese phone number looks like that.

961 3 123456

**961**: the country code. i want it to be valid with or without it.

**3**: the area code. here's where it is tricky. the possible area codes are 03, 70 and 71. when the country code is present, 03 drops the 0 and becomes 3 while 70 and 71 are as is with or without country code.

**123456**: the phone number, always 6 digits.

here are the formats i'm trying to validate:

961 3 123456
961 70 123456
961 71 123456
03 123456
70 123456
71 123456

the spaces are here just for the sake of clarity, i am validating after stripping all spaces and non alphanumeric characters.

that's it, would be great if someone can help.
thanks

Comment: why should be someone press the 0 for areacode 3, when it will be dropped? this makes no sense for me, because it is another phone number with or without the 0.

Comment: the number 03 123456 can be written in two ways: 03123456 or 9613123456

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure there's a slicker way to do it, but

```
^(961(3|70|71)|(03|70|71))\d{6}$
```

seems to work, assuming I understand the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

`^((961)?(7(0|1))|(961|0)3)[0-9]{6}$`

It's a composition of these three regexes:

```
(961)?(7(0|1))  // 70 and 71 prefixes
(961|0)3        // (0)3 prefix
[0-9]{6}        // main number
```

Answer (score 2):

Allowing for spaces or common separator chars (though I know you said you weren't concerned about them):

```
^((961[\s+-]*(3|7(0|1)))|(03|7(0|1)))[\s+-]*\d{6}$
```

http://regexr.com?2t89v

Answer (score 2):

This regex handle all the area codes in lebanon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Lebanon

```
^(?:\+961|961)?(1|0?3[0-9]?|[4-6]|70|71|76|78|79|7|81?|9)\d{6}$
```

[You can check on regexr](https://regexr.com/4ar2e)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers (or an accepted answer), please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we were working on application and needed to validate Lebanese landline and mobile numbers. This regex can validate the format of all Lebanese phone numbers:

```
^((?:\+961|00961)([1-9]|70|71|76|78|79|81)|(0[1-9]|70|71|76|78|79|81))\d{6}$
```

This regex can validate all numbers with or without country code `+961` or `00961` and if the numbers have leading zeros like `01 03 04 05 06 07 07 08 09` we need to ensure that the zero is not found when country code exists else we need to keep the zero.

Of course this regex can be enhanced where some area codes start with certain numbers like `76` the six digit number can't start with `2`.