# Validate Phone Prefix With Country Code : IF vs RegEx

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP regex for Lebanese phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212341/php-regex-for-lebanese-phone-number)
>   [preg_replace to mask parts of a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651744/preg-replace-to-mask-parts-of-a-phone-number)

in my country, there are 3 possibilities input for phone number prefix : +62, 62 and 0.

for example :

> +622112345, 622112345 and 02112345

now, the problem is... I want to store phone number in just 1 format, that is : 0xxxx. means, any phone prefix will be converted into 0xxxx format.

> Input : +622112345, Output : 02112345
>
> Input : 622112345, Output : 02112345
>
> Input : 02112345, Output : 02112345

I thought by using substr() function and IF will solve this situation :

```
$Prefix = substr($Number, 0, 2);

if ($Prefix = "+6"){
//some code to convert +62 into 0
}else if ($Prefix = "62"){
//some code to convert 62 into 0
}else{
//nothing to do, because it's already 0
}
```

is there any methods to do this beside using IF? with RegEx, for example...

Comment: This has been answered, albeit for other countries, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212341/php-regex-for-lebanese-phone-number) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651744/preg-replace-to-mask-parts-of-a-phone-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is much easier in a single regex:

```
preg_match( '/(0|\+?\d{2})(\d{7,8})/', $input, $matches);
echo $matches[1] . ' is the extension.' . "\n";
echo $matches[2] . ' is the phone number.' . "\n";
```

This will capture both the extension and the phone number from either input. However, for your specific cases, we can create a test bench and use `preg_replace()` to get the desired output string:

```
$tests = array( '+622112345' => '02112345', '622112345' => '02112345', '02112345' => '02112345');

foreach( $tests as $test => $desired_output) {
    $output = preg_replace( '/(0|\+?\d{2})(\d{7,8})/', '0$2', $test);
    echo "Does $output match $desired_output? " . ((strcmp( $output, $desired_output) === 0) ? "Yes" : "No") . "\n";
}
```

You can see from [the demo](http://viper-7.com/kKB02v) that this is properly creating the correct `$output` string for all of the test cases.

Comment: bro, your code gives me this : Input : +622112345, Output : 02112345 (Correct); Input : 622112345, Output : 02112345 (Correct again); Input : 081212345, Output : 01212345 (Missing 8, Should be 081212345)

Comment: What's up with the CAPS? The problem is `(\d{7})`, it assumes the phone number is 7 digits. If it can be 7 or 8, change it to `(\d{7,8})`.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for 7 or 8 digit phone numbers, which you can see [here](http://viper-7.com/yTA9hB) that is passes all of your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('[^\+62|62]', $your_phone_number)) {
    # if string contains +62 or 62 do something with this number
} else {
    # do nothing because string doesn't contain +62 or 62
}
```

That's just shorter